# Scroll down in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

is it possible to scroll down in Visual Studio 2022 just as if I was using scroll wheel? Say for example using some shortcut. I want to keep the cursor at the same line I am at, but move the code a little higher on the screen, without getting my hands off keyboard.

Comment: Ctrl + Up or Ctrl + Down scrolls the screen without moving the cursor, unless it falls out of view.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in the comments, the default keybinding for this are <kbd>Ctrl+Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Down</kbd>.  Keyboard shortcuts can also be reconfigured in the Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard settings.

The commands to configure are `Edit.ScrollLineUp` and `Edit.ScrollLineDown`.  There are several other scroll related commands, but I'm not sure what all of them do (they may not be applicable in the text editor).

[image: keyboard settings for scroll related commands]